# R : spls getting error "Error in one %*% y : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"

Tags: r

I'm having problem trying to use the `spls` package in R. I'm a newbie and keep getting the following error:

```
library(spls)
data(iris)
TrainData <- iris[,1:4]
TrainClasses <- iris[,5]
cv1 <- cv.spls(TrainData,TrainClasses,eta = seq(0.1,0.9,0.1), K = c(1:3))
# eta = 0.1 
# Error in one %*% y : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `cv.spls` doesn't like to have a factor variable for the y vector of responses. This seems to work

```
TrainClasses <- model.matrix(~Species+0, data=iris)
cv1 <- cv.spls(TrainData, TrainClasses, 
    eta = seq(0.1,0.9,0.1), K = c(1:3))
```

or

```
TrainClasses <- as.numeric(iris[,5])
cv1 <- cv.spls(TrainData, TrainClasses, 
    eta = seq(0.1,0.9,0.1), K = c(1:3))
```

depending on how you want to interpret the species.

Comment: I think you have identified the problem correctly, but I'm not sure if your solution will give the expected result. I think you want to get a `matrix` of `y` responses. Otherwise, you are implying a linear relationship (the third level is three times the first level) among the three variables. For a binary response, this would be fine.

Comment: Good point @nograpes. I've changed the answer to show a method for categorical data.

Comment: Thanks nograpes and MrFlick. Mmm.. it will take some time until I can feel comfortable with R (and also statistics). I tried "plot(my_sim, what = "observations", show.names = FALSE)" and it plots the observation plot as expected. Is there a way to assign different color or symbol to the two well separated "groups" in the plot ?

Comment: If you have a different question, its best to start a new post. New questions unrelated to the original should not be asked in the comments.